# Laravel iconv, mbstring and bcrypt issues after uploading

Tags: laravel, iconv, mbstring

PHP v 5.4.2, Mcrypt enabled, iconv enabled, every requirements are met.

The project works fine in my production machine (obviously). However, once i have uploaded it to the server I have been facing one problem after another.

[image]

It's a shared hosting where I do not have access to the php.ini or cannot install any programs. However, since all the requirements are met I believe none are needed anyways. What could be causing this and what would be the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with with the server itself. It did not have PHP Mbstring support enabled. Once the admin enabled it, the issue was resolved.